# AjaxControlToolkit.dll.refresh

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ajaxcontext

What is the role of AjaxControlToolkit.dll.refresh file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*.dll.refresh files are a very simple file telling the project where the external reference exists. http://monsur.xanga.com/437206798/dllrefresh-and-aspnet/

They allow the project to update the reference. If you open it in a text editor, you'll see it just holds a path to the reference.